# How to replace string by an escape character plus string in unix

Tags: unix

How can I convert a one line like below:

```
794170|VWSD|AAA|e|h|i|j|STRING1|794170|VWSD|BBB|q|w|e|r|STRING2|794170|VWSD|CCC|z|x|c|v|STRING3|...and so on
```

to a linefeed-delimted,

Expected Output:

```
794170|VWSD|AAA|e|h|i|j|STRING1|
794170|VWSD|BBB|q|w|e|r|STRING2|
794170|VWSD|CCC|z|x|c|v|STRING3|
```

and so on.
BTW I'n not a unix expert and just want steps or simple commands to resolve. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix/Bash and belongs on [unix.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have your string in a file with name "x", then you can do this.
I use the character ":" to represent the carriage return that 'sed' adds to your string. Choose something else if ":" occurs in your string. Then "tr" changes ":" to carriage return. The output is as you desire except that there is an extra carriage return at the beginning.

```
cat x | sed 's/794170/:794170/g' | tr ':' "\n"
```

Comment: it worked mate! I'd just change colon : to grave accent (`) as there are valid colons in the file and also to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fold` command:

```
$ fold -w32 file
794170|VWSD|AAA|e|h|i|j|STRING1|
794170|VWSD|BBB|q|w|e|r|STRING2|
794170|VWSD|CCC|z|x|c|v|STRING3|
```

Comment: I can't use fold since length of strings and characters are varying for any row but the first field (794170) and second field (VWSD) are always similar for any row.

Comment: The only information I was going off was your example which **is** fixed width! Maybe if you actually explain you problem clearly you would have gotten a suitable answer. Who ever down voted this answer and up voted @KitAlmario comment must be a mind reader, congrats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a simple command. There are several options for creating scripts that can split lines more or less arbitrarily. Any Unix will have the awk utility available. On most systems you will also find Python and Perl. My guess is that a Perl or Python script is the easiest way to split lines like the one you gave.

This would be one way to do it in Python

```
inline = "794170|VWSD|AAA|e|h|i|j|STRING1|794170|VWSD|BBB|q|w|e|r|STRING2|794170|VWSD|CCC|z|x|c|v|STRING3|"

splits = ['794170' + s for s in inline.split('794170')]

for s in splits[1:]:
   print s

794170|VWSD|AAA|e|h|i|j|STRING1|
794170|VWSD|BBB|q|w|e|r|STRING2|
794170|VWSD|CCC|z|x|c|v|STRING3|
```

Comment: fold, as suggested by @sudo_O, will work if your chunks are always fixed width.

Comment: Unfortunately, column fields are varying as I'd mentioned with @sudo_O. Sorry I'm not familiar with Perl and Python, can you show me how it is used here? I'm more comfortable dealing with tr and awks, and sed (least).